# Store values in client computer permanently?

Tags: client-side, store, datastore

Is there a way to store values on client side permanently?

I have a site, flash game (the game is not developed by me, of course), after you registered, it will recognize you even after u close browser, clear cache and cookies, and even restart computer and modem. Where do they store the values? Why the flash game can recognize me after few days?

After research in google, I still cant get the answer. My guess is, is it stored in my computer RAM? How could it possible? If my guess is true, how do we store values in RAM??

FYI:

The flash game is created in : AS3

Comment: RAM is not a possible answer. Once you switch off, everything goes away from RAM!

Comment: Soooo... where could it be? Any ideas?

Comment: Check my answer and the Wikipedia link in it. You will get an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RAM is not perisistent with reboots. So its not possible to remember anything stored in RAM even after a single reboot. I have read about something called "[Local Shared Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object)" which are a bit more than the normal ones. Clearing normal caches/cookies wont clear them away.

Comment: Looks like its the LSO. I havent read the details though. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

It's probably stored on the server, and the client is recognised by IP address and maybe also browser id string.

Comment: IP? What if client has dynamic IP?? Well, I tested different browsers as well (signup on FF, change to safari n chrome to login, still can login)

Comment: in this case it would be IP. There's no way browsers would share their own data.

Comment: um.. I donnu why this answer been vote up, cuz I really dont think its IP. IP not stable -> dynamic IP users.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a [**Flash Cookie**](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/05/04/flash-cookies-explained/)?

Comment: Sounds pretty likely to me :)

Comment: Cool.. Flash cookie = LSO. I think thats the answer. But sorry, best answer would goes to piotr, as he is the one who give me the answer..

Comment: Sory, i mean aviator, not piotr

Answer (score 0):

Can't store in RAM if you're saying that it remembers you after reboot.

Your modem have an IP and also another ID which can be in this form:

c9067688.static.spo.virtua.com.br

Maybe it's taking this ID...

Comment: I see. So, where could it be stored then, any ideas? I cleared both cookies and cache, but it still recognize me.. Really beat me..

Answer (score 0):

the game recognizes you only after logging in to the site or just open the url..??

if it recognizes you after login, then its probably stored it in a server.

Comment: Nope. Recognize when I visit the site, havent login :(

Comment: did u check remember user on the machine??

Comment: There is no this function(remember me). There is "user selection" function, which u can choose users created on that computer. Not really a login, just select the user, and it recognize u, ur money/coins/ level etc..